# List view in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I am following this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwqTsxyhQAU  and trying to make a simple webpage with a listview. However, I have followed the video exactly and have the same code, however I am not getting the same listview as in the video. Please can someone help me out; Below are my screenshots:

What I should have:

[image: What I should have]

But instead, I am getting this:

[image: But instead, I am getting this]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>List App</h1>
        </header>

        <!--Article, main text for the web page-->
        <article data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li>
                    <a href="#test">
                        <h1>This is a test</h1>
                        <img src="Images/test.png" alt="Test image" />
                        <p>This is a image test to see if it works</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#test">
                        <h1>This is a test 2</h1>
                        <img src="Images/test.png" alt="Test image" />
                        <p>This is a image test 2 to see if it works</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </article>


        <!--Footer here-->
        <footer data-role="footer">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be because you have different jquery version "jquery-1.9.1.min.js"

Comment: you did not use any styles. so maybe thats why the images are so different..

Comment: Hi Henry, I have to use the latest version of jquery, that video was made in 2012

Comment: Hi wrick17, I am following the youtube video, I am new to jquery and in the video I am following, the person has not created any styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version used in the video is old and you're using latest release 1.4. The image should be first child of the anchor.

```
<li>
  <a href="#test">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="Welcome to JS Bin">
    <h1>This is a test 2</h1>
    <p>This is a image test 2 to see if it works</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: is there any useful guides on jquery I can read on, I am new to jquery

Comment: @Mikey start with jquery mobile demo page. also look up some jquery mobile dedicated blogs. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/ https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20mobile%20blogs%20hints&rct=j#q=jquery+mobile+blogs+hints